# using `\@ifnextchar` to lookahead for `.`

Tags: macros, xetex

i'm trying to **write a command that checks whether the next character after it is invoked is a dot** (`.`), but can't seem to figure it out.

i'm kinda new to LaTeX and have written a command to stylize the writing of centuries. the command adds the `.` character in the end by default. the problem is that, if I use it at the end of a sentence, I end up with two dots (`..`). i'm trying to lookahead for the next character to see if it's a dot or not, in order to conditionally decide whether to add a dot at the end. i tried using the `\@ifnextchar` marco, but can't seem to figure it out (despite searching through the TeX StackExchange and the docs). what am i doing wrong?

**update with minimal working example**:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcommand{\scl}[1]{%
    % #1 : the century in question
    #1%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{I}}{\up{er}}{\up{ème}}%
    ~s%
    \@ifnextchar.{}{.}% this is the line that causes a problem: checks if next char is `.`
}

\begin{document}
    This is where I use the command \scl{XIX}. Ideally, the command 
    should not have added a `.` since it is followed by a dot.
\end{document}
```

**output:**

I just found out that without using `rotating` (which was loaded before I made this command), I get the following error: `Undefined control sequence. This is where I use the command \scl{XIX}`. When using `rotating`, this is the output:

[image: output]

for info, i use XeLaTeX on TeXstudio.

**thanks for your help !**

Comment: have you made this definition at a point `@` is a letter? (in a package  or after `\makeatletter`)? Please always provide full examples, we can not run your code and you have not shown the error you got.

Comment: I just edited my post with a MWE working example, error log and screen capture, sorry to have forgotten that ! i didn't use `\makeatletter`, but adding that solved the issue, so thanks !!

Comment: Don't load `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`! First: You're using XeLaTeX, that doesn't need `inputenc` as it is a unicode engine. Second: It is very dated, nowadays `utf8` is better than `utf8x` in pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Also, even if it does no harm here (since `\@ifnextchar` ignores spaces) you really should put the `%` immediately after the closing brace to remove the spurious space here as well (or else it'll need to ignore that space on every call)

Answer (score 1):

You need `@` to be a letter:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
% no: (ignored with xetex) \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
% no: does real harm with xetex (breaks hyphenation) \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{rotating}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scl}[1]{%
    % #1 : the century in question
    #1%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{I}}{\up{er}}{\up{ème}}%
    ~s%
    \@ifnextchar.{}{. }% this is the line that causes a problem: checks if next char is `.`
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    This is where I use the command \scl{XIX}. Ideally, the command 
    should not have added a `.` since it is followed by a dot.

    This is where I use the command \scl{XIX} ideally, the command 
    should  have added a `.` since it is not followed by a dot.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! indeed, that's what was missing, i don't know why i hadn't thought about it before.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `\makeatletter` to allow `\@ifnextchar` to be interpreted correctly.

As other have commented, never use `utf8x` (with any engine) and don't load neither `fontenc` nor `lmodern` with Unicode engines (XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX).

Your command is missing robustness and wouldn't work in section titles or captions, for instance. Use

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\scl}[1]{...}
```

instead.

An even more robust implementation with `expl3` would be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\scl}{m}
 {% #1 : the century in question
  #1
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { I } { #1 }{\up{er}}{\up{ème}}
  \nobreakspace s
  \peek_charcode:NF . { . }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is where I use the command \scl{XIX}. Ideally, the command 
should not have added a `.' since it is followed by a period.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in my opinion, it would be easier inputting a standard numeral rather than a Roman one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\scl}{m}
 {% #1 : the century in question in standard numeric form
  \int_to_Roman:n { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 1 }{\up{er}}{\up{ème}}
  \nobreakspace s
  \peek_charcode:NF . { . }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is where I use the command \scl{19}. Ideally, the command 
should not have added a `.' since it is followed by a period.

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

It's even possible to have both types of input (not that I recommend it, though).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\scl}{m}
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A [0-9]* \Z } { #1 }
   {% the input is numeric
    \int_to_Roman:n { #1 }
    \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 1 }{\up{er}}{\up{ème}}
   }
   {% assume the input is a Roman numeral
    #1
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { I } { #1 }{\up{er}}{\up{ème}}
   }
  \nobreakspace s
  \peek_charcode:NF . { . }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This is where I use the command \scl{19}. Ideally, the command 
should not have added a `.' since it is followed by a period.

This is where I use the command \scl{XIX}. Ideally, the command 
should not have added a `.' since it is followed by a period.

\end{document}
```

Two copies of the same text are generated.

Comment: thanks for the very detailed answer ! adding `\makeatletter` worked, i don't know why i never thought about it.